Korean movie, a girl can see ghosts/fairy
I was watching an segement of movie kind of an ad on facebook. 
As far I remember, there is school girl aged 8-10 years may be;
can see ghosts. She was in her school when suddenly saw a ghost and tries to disturb the her.
While the girl goes home, the school ghost (female ghost) follows her and tells her to come back to school.
The girl get pissed off and she uses an Umbrella (Yellow in color; has some writing on it.) to wade off.
That trick doesnt work, then a gentle man (wearing a black suit) comes into the picture and wade off the school ghost with black umbrella hitting on the ground.
Then girl and gentle man have some conversation on bring back something that belongs to him, in some place.
The girl agrees to get it and she goes into a house lit up with lots of candles and mirror.
There she retrieves what ever she needed, but while exiting, she end-up with another ghost/fairy (Loney ghost) who tries to be cool with the girl.
This lonely ghost learns that she was sent by other ghost that cannot enter his house.
(Loney ghost is bound by 5 candles) that chained (not exactly chained, just like captured of some sort) him to stay inside of that house.
Loney ghost promises (makes a contract) with the girl, if she blow out the candles, he will protect from ghosts.
And that it I know, its an korean movie. I forgot to see the movie as I was disturbed by something else. haha.

This doesnt make sense putting up on hold as off-topic. question has sufficient details related to it. never mind. i got the answer for it.

Watched this, realize its a Drama not a movie.

The answer issssss... HWayugi.
you can see as per linked below. Hope this helps!
https://www.soompi.com/2017/12/27/first-impressions-hwayugi-brings-sharp-wit-fantastic-performances-thrilling-fantasy/

Great.and Thanks. could how did you find it?. Its english name is different.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.

http://kissdrama.club/download/a-korean-odyssey
attached the downlink. hardsub english..
hope this helps!
